# I have an index out of bound excetion on JFrame.setContentPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, indexoutofboundsexception

This line :

```
this.setContentPane(panelLoading);
```

Give me this error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.remove(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.remove(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.remove(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.remove(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.setContentPane(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.setContentPane(Unknown Source)
at IHM.FenPrincipale.chargement(FenPrincipale.java:291)
at IHM.FenPrincipale.setServeur(FenPrincipale.java:175)
at IHM.PanelMenuPrincipal.actionPerformed(PanelMenuPrincipal.java:174)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This error appear on the next setContentPane after using my function to set my database, only if the function is called from an event on a JComboBox (ActionListener or ItemListener).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==boutonJouer){
        fen.setServeur(serveur.getSelectedItem().toString());//The bug doesn't appear
    }else if(e.getSource()==serveur){
        fen.setServeur(serveur.getSelectedItem().toString());//The bug appear
    }
}
```

boutonJouer is a JButton, and serveur is a JComboBox.
Please help me.

PS: sorry for my english

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: You really should avoid using `setContentPane` to switch out views, either simply update the existing view with the new data or if required use a `CardLayout` to switch between views

Comment: Thank you for the CardLayout, with this solution the bug doesn't appear but my JComboBox is display on the panelLoading, how can I solve this bug ?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you MadProgrammer for the CardLayout, I finaly find the solution :
Use CardLayout and remove JcomboBox before call the function and add her after.

```
remove(serveur); //Remove the JComboBox
fen.setServeur(serveur.getSelectedItem().toString()); //Call the function
add(serveur); //Then add the JCombpBox
```

It works.
Thanks you for your help.